# Can we make the Pokemon GO tag harder to post in?

Tags: discussion, tags, pokemon

Currently, Gaming.SE is being inundated with posts regarding the "account glitch," wherein players are forced to re-create their accounts from scratch.

Is there some way we can add a sticky or some sort of notification forcing new users to read the existing posts instead of creating new (and useless) duplicates?

Comment: We could pop it up in huge, bright red letters and users would still skip it like they do all EULAs and other website popups

Comment: If we try to warn them, they'll ignore the warning.  
If we restrict the use of the tag, they'll just stop using the tag.  
If we stop them from posting question, they'll post them as answers.

Comment: It's a great idea, however, it doesn't take user's persistence into account at all.  If they really want to post it, they'll post it, damn the barriers.

Comment: @Frank Still, if we stop one or two from posting a dumb question once they see there's already an answer, that would still be good.

Comment: The effort involved to stop those one or two far outstrips the value in stopping those one or two, I feel.

Comment: Do we have an answered question that we can duplicate them all to?

Comment: @Studoku I bet the more dedicated users have a list of the most common problems somewhere. I've been pining for such list somewhere here, tough, just to make marking duplicates a bit easier and/or faster.

Comment: @Studoku depends on the exact issue, but here are some recent popular ones: [my account reset with latest update](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/278248/pokemon-go-login-issues-after-update), [here is my username, i dunno my email address](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/277034/forgot-login-credentials-can-i-look-up-my-account-from-my-username), [i dont remember my password](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/273370/is-it-possible-to-log-back-into-a-pokemon-go-account)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## No

Pokémon Go has brought a huge amount of new traffic to the site, and a lot of it is from people who don't necessarily have a grasp on how we're different to fora they may be used to.

We already have adequate tools to help people get the answers they need (putting questions on hold, or marking as dupes). Yes, the load on the site's reviewers and mods has gone up a bit, but it's still *well* within what we have the capacity to handle (mod and review queues are empty at time of posting).